# How to fix MIDI playback on OS X?

Tags: mac-os-x, java, sound

Sometimes sounds specified using `SoundNote` (i.e. things played using MIDI) don't play properly on OS X.  Some notes are missing and some are stuck.

At least this is what happens on my system with Mathematica 9.0.1 on OS X 10.8.4 and Apple Java 1.6.0_51.

How can I fix this and have Mathematica play MIDI properly?

Note: [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18777/how-would-i-improve-this-karaoke-machine-code) is affected as well.

Comment: This is of interest to me.  and [perhaps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zF8SYLjl07g)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to happen [because of a problem or incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148898/java-midi-in-mac-osx-broken) with Apple's version of Java, which Mathematica uses by default.  (Mathematica does not ship with Java on OS X.)

I believe this could be fixed by changing the *default* Java of the system to be Oracle's Java 7, but I did not want to do that for various reasons (Java 7 doesn't have retina support).

The following solution worked for me: if you install the [Java 7 internet plugin](http://java.com/), it won't change the version of Java used to run applications (the default version).  It will only change the Java used for the browser plugin.  You can still ask Mathematica to use this Java installation using something like

```
<<JLink`
ReinstallJava[
 CommandLine -> 
  "/Library/Internet\\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java"]
```

Now `SoundNote` sounds will play fine.

Comment: Some of this was already explained by Arnoud, but I ran into the problem again, so I thought it would be good to put the solution into its own QA.